# (Android) Hide installation source from app

Tags: side-loading, apk

I tried to install a banking app on my device. The issue is not actually root detection (which I expected); it does not seem to care about my device being rooted. What is an issue though, is that I do not want to use the Play Store. However, when installing it via for example the Aurora Store, the app shows the following:

`App download not trustworthy`

> This app was transferred as part of a change of device or not downloaded from the official Google Play Store. For security reasons, we ask you to uninstall the app, then download it again from the official Google Play Store.

Is there any way to make the app believe it was installed from Google Play, without actually doing that?

Comment: It seems that you can (or could?) fakte the value if you install the apk manually via adb: `adb shell pm install -i "com.android.vending" -r <path to apk on the phone>.apk` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26272850/150978